# What is the best way to call database values into a Magento static block?

Tags: magento

I apologize if this is a very basic question, but I wanted to know what would be the best way to do this.

I have a Magento store and I want to insert a static block in my product description.  Not sure how to go about that...

I want the static blocks to also call product specifications, so they automatically update on the description when I update the attribute.  When I click on the "Insert Variable" button, only a limited amount of values come up.  Is there a way that I can expand this list to add product specifications such as manufacturer, height, finish, etc?

Any suggestions in how to do this?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native way that I know of to call custom or dynamic variables inside of product description fields.

You can call in a static block that return the appropriate attribute value.  To do this...

1. Install the [Static Blocks Everywhere extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/static-blocks-everywhere-3112.html) so you can use block code tags inside of product descriptions.
2. Create a new template file in: `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/view/attribute_block.phtml`
3. In your `attribute_block.phtml` template file, paste in the following code:

   ```
   <?php
   $_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
   $attribute_code = $this->getAttributeCode();

   if($_product && $attribute_code) {
       $attribute_value = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

       echo $attribute_value;
   }
   ```
4. Use the following block code in your product descriptions:

   `{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/view/attribute_block.phtml" attribute_code="color"}}`

   *Change the `color` in `attribute_code="color"` to the attribute code value you wish to load for this product
5. Make sure the **Visible on Product View Page on Front-end** setting for your  **attribute** is set to `Yes`.  Look under **Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > *Edit your attribute**

With everything setup, you should now be able to call in product attribute values in your descriptions.  For example, the following:

```
The color of this product is <strong>{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/view/attribute_block.phtml" attribute_code="color"}}</strong> and the name is <strong>{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/view/attribute_block.phtml" attribute_code="name"}}</strong>.`
```

Will output:

> The color of this product is **Black** and the name is **My Black
>   Product**.

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate you taking the time to write out these very straight forward instructions.  I tried the extension Static Blocks Everywhere and once installed my site (and admin area) stopped working.  Is there a way enable the static blocks in the products description without an extension?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "admin area stopped working", that's kind of vague for me to know what the actual problem is.  And no, you need an extension to enable static blocks in product descriptions.  Magento does not provide this functionality standard.

Comment: The site would no longer load (neither the admin area or the site).  I didn't get an error that I could see on the browser, it just would not load.  I think the extension might not be compatible with my theme (Argento).

Comment: **1.** How did you install it?  Did you use Magento Connect? **2.** Did you flush your caches after installing? **3.** What version of Magento are you using, is it listed as compatible with this extension?  **4.** When you go to the admin, what specifically do you see, just a blank white page?

Comment: I am using Magento version 1.7.0.2.  I installed the extension using Magento Connect.  After that it asks me if I want to clear the cache and a refresh button appeared, clicked on that.  But when I go back to the admin area the page is completely blank (white page).  When I check the site, only the header loads. When I uninstall the extension using Magento Connect and go back to the admin, it loads properly. Hope that answers all your questions.  Thanks again!

Comment: Delete everything in your `var/cache` directory and try again.  If that doesn't work, look for the `error_log` in your Magento root directory and see if it's reporting an error.